# How to submit multiple value in asp form

Tags: jsp, servlets

In the PHP when I click submit the server will get all the submit value via $_POST

So how can I do same like that with asp

```
<form name="submitForm" method="post" action="cart?action=update">
    <c:forEach var="product" items="${products}">
        <input type="text" name="${product.productID}" value="${product.quantity}" />
    </c:forEach>
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

I want after submitting, I can get only one value in the servlet and the value consists multiple input value without give it a particular name.

I tried

```
System.out.println(request.getParameterValues("submitForm"));
```

But its null

Could anyone point me out ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, `${product.productID}` is having different value in each record. Use the values from here to get the values in the server side. e.g. if `${product.productID}` results into `productId1, productId2, prductId3....`, retireve the values as:

```
      request.getParameter("productId1");
      request.getParameter("productId2");
      request.getParameter("productId3");
      ......
```

If you are unsure about the names to retrieve, you may get them all parameter names using `request.getParameterNames()`. e.g. below:

```
    Enumeration<String> parEnumeration = request.getParameterNames();
    while (parEnumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
        String parameterName = parEnumeration.nextElement();
        String parameterValue = request.getParameter(parameterName);
        System.out.println("Parameter Name= " + parameterName);
        System.out.println("Parameter Value= " + parameterValue);
    }
```

Hope  this helps.

Comment: Thanks your hint. the getParameterNames return an Enumeration. So how could I retrieve it value and it name for each record. Such as {name="product1": value=3}

Answer (score 0):

`submitForm` is the form name and not the field identifier. Hence, trying to get parameter values for a field named `submitForm` will return null.

You should ideally change the name of the text field from `${product.productId}` to something definite, such as `"MyProducts"`, and then do the call on that.